# SQL query to fetch output using table variables & join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a SQL query to fetch the data of one table and join it with some more data either using multiple or nested SQL statements or using table variable and then use join later.

The condition is that if the `Medium` column in `Spends Table` is `TV` then in the `Output Table` the `TV_Spends` should show the `Spends` of TV and that particular market & Brand. And this same is for Medium `Print`.

Also, another condition is that if the `Type` column in `Spends Table` is **CWB** then the Spends of that `Primary_Brand` and `Medium` should NOT be used in `TV_Spends` and `Print_Spends` calculation.

`Total_Spends` is sum of `TV_Spends` and `Print_Spends` for that `Brand_Key` & `Market`

**Spends Table**

| Primary_Brand_Key | Medium | Market | Type | Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kornet | TV | UK | NULL | 1000 |
| Kornet | TV | Poland | NULL | 2000 |
| Kornet | Print | Poland | NULL | 3000 |
| Kornet | Print | NULL | CWB | 7000 |
| Tamas | TV | UK | NULL | 9000 |

**Expected Output Table**

| Primary_Brand | Market | TV_Spends | Print_Spends | Total_Spends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kornet | UK | 1000 | NULL | 1000 |
| Kornet | Poland | 2000 | 3000 | 5000 |
| Tamas | UK | 9000 | NULL | 9000 |

**Output Coming**

| Primary_Brand | Market | TV_Spends | Print_Spends | Total_Spends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1000 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5000 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 9000 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 3000 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 2000 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 9000 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | UK | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | Poland | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | UK | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Kornet | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Kornet | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Tamas | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

**SQL Query I have written which is giving the `Output Coming` output, However the Output should be `Expected Output Table`:-**

```
declare @output_table_spends table
(
primary_brand_var nvarchar(255),
market_var nvarchar(255),
tv_spends decimal(11,2),
print_spends decimal(11,2)
total_spends_var  decimal(11,2)
)

Insert into @output_table_spends (primary_brand_var)
select Primary_Brand_Key from
dbo.Spends

Insert into @output_table_spends (market_var)
select Market from
dbo.Spends

Insert into @output_table_spends (tv_spends)
select sum(Amount_Spent_INR) 
  from dbo.Spends
  where medium='TV'
  group by Market
  
  Insert into @output_table_spends (print_spends)
select sum(Amount_Spent_INR) 
  from dbo.Spends
  where medium='Print'
  group by Market
  
  Insert into @output_table_spends (total_spends_var)
select sum(tv_spends,print_spends) 
  from dbo.Spends
  group by Market
  
  select * from dbo.Spends
  
  select distinct A.Primary_Brand_Key, A.Market, 
  B.tv_spends, B.print_spends, B.total_spends_var 
   from dbo.Spends A
  inner join @output_table_spends B
  on A.Primary_Brand_Key=B.primary_brand_var
  group by A.Primary_Brand_Key, A.Market, B.tv_spends, B.print_spends, B.total_spends_var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following what you want, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select primary_brand_key, market,
       sum(case when medium = 'TV' and type <> 'CWB' then spends else 0 end) as tv,
       sum(case when medium = 'print' and type <> 'CWB' then spends else 0 end) as print,
       sum(spends)
from spends s
group by primary_brand_key, market;
```

Your question suggests that the `'CWB'` is only needed for the `tv` and `print` columns.  However, if you really want it for all three, then use a `where` clause instead.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. Worked like charm.

Can you please also help me with the 'CWB' issue. its in the 3rd paragraph of this question

Comment: This does not actually return the results in the sample output

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a group by and sum to aggregate the values and then only use the NULL values for `s.[Type]`.  I used this to test:
NOTE: you could put NULL in instead of the `0` in the CASE IF you really want NULL not 0.

```
DECLARE @Spends AS TABLE 
(Primary_Brand_Key VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 [Medium] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 Market VARCHAR(10)  NULL,
 [Type] VARCHAR(10) NULL,
 Spent INT)
 
 INSERT INTO @Spends
  ( Primary_Brand_Key, [Medium], Market, [Type], Spent )
VALUES
('Kornet',  'TV',   'UK',   NULL,   1000),
('Kornet',  'TV',   'Poland',   NULL,   2000),
('Kornet',  'Print',    'Poland',   NULL,   3000),
('Kornet',  'Print',        NULL,   'CWB',  7000),
('Tamas',   'TV',   'UK',   NULL,   9000);

SELECT 
    s.primary_brand_key AS Primary_Brand,
    s.Market,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.[medium] = 'TV' THEN s.Spent ELSE 0 END) AS TV_Spends,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.[medium] = 'Print' THEN s.Spent ELSE 0 END) AS Print_Spends,
    SUM(s.Spent) AS Total_Spends
FROM @Spends AS s
WHERE s.[Type] IS NULL
GROUP BY s.primary_brand_key, s.market
ORDER BY Total_Spends;
```

This returns these results

```
Primary_Brand   Market  TV_Spends   Print_Spends    Total_Spends
Kornet             UK       1000       0               1000
Kornet         Poland       2000    3000               5000
Tamas              UK       9000       0               9000
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark.

However, I am getting duplicate records when I use left join with other table

Comment: HI @Mark. I had to use joins to join with another table, and after this TV_Spends & Print_Spends are not coming side by side, they are coming one below the another. How this can be fixed?

Comment: You need to perhaps ask a new question with your example code and the tables, perhaps similar to the example I gave so people asking can quickly assist you properly