# SQL query to remove data duplication when join is used

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a SQL query to remove data duplication when join is used. Requesting you to kindly check ***Expected Output*** table & ***Output Coming*** table for understanding the exact issue.

**Brand Table**

| Primary_Brand_Key | Medium | Market | Type | Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kornet | TV | UK | NULL | 1000 |
| Kornet | TV | Poland | NULL | 2000 |
| Kornet | Print | Poland | NULL | 3000 |
| Kornet | Print | NULL | CWB | 7000 |
| Tamas | TV | UK | NULL | 9000 |

**Food Table**

| Primary_Brand_Key | Food |
| --- | --- |
| Kornet | Yes |
| Tamas | No |

**Expected Output :-**

| Primary_Brand | Market | Type | Food | TV_Spends | Print_Spends | Total_Spends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kornet | UK | NULL | Yes | 1000 | NULL | 1000 |
| Kornet | Poland | NULL | Yes | 2000 | 3000 | 5000 |
| Kornet | NULL | CWB | Yes | NULL | 0 | 0 |
| Tamas | UK | NULL | No | 9000 | NULL | 9000 |

**Output Coming**

| Primary_Brand | Market | Type | Food | TV_Spends | Print_Spends | Total_Spends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kornet | UK | NULL | Yes | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| Kornet | UK | NULL | Yes | 2000 | 0 | 2000 |
| Kornet | Poland | CWB | Yes | 2000 | 3000 | 5000 |
| Kornet | Poland | NULL | Yes | 3000 | 0 | 5000 |
| Tamas | UK | NULL | No | 9000 | 0 | 9000 |

**Updated SQL Query :-**

```
SELECT t.Primary_Brand_Key as Primary_Brand
     , t.Market
     , t.Type
     , f.Food
     , t.TV_Spends
     , t.Print_Spends
     , t.Total_Spends
FROM Food f
RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT Primary_Brand_Key "Primary_Brand_Key"
                  , Market "Market",
                  Type "Type",
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN Medium = 'TV'
                                THEN Spent
                        END) "TV_Spends"
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN Medium = 'Print'
                                THEN Spent
                        END) "Print_Spends"
                    , sum(distinct Spent) "Total_Spends"
             FROM Brand
             WHERE Market IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY Primary_Brand_Key
                    , Market , Type) t
        ON f.Primary_Brand_Key = t.Primary_Brand_Key

group by t.Primary_Brand_Key, t.Market,t.Type,f.Food,t.TV_Spends, t.Print_Spends, t.Total_Spends
ORDER BY f.food DESC, t.Market DESC;
```

Comment: Enter sample data from two tables so we can help you

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Added sample table

Comment: So - multiple accounts? [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68423660/sql-query-to-fetch-output-using-table-variables-join)

Comment: Search this site for `[sql-server] columns to rows` and `[sql-server] pivot data`. This sort of question has been asked and answered multiple times here.

Comment: And your query generates a syntax error as posted - so it is not "working fine" with or without the join.

Comment: @Smor : I have all the rights to ask questions from multiple accounts as long as the questions are different

Comment: @KenWhite : Thanks for pointing it out, but this question is not related to that. It is related to something like that in the output the values of TV spends & Print Spends are not coming next to each other. Join helped,

Comment: @BerguruAdmin: It is related to that, and sock puppet accounts are discouraged here when the questions are very similar. Why do you need multiple accounts if you're not trying to be deceptive?

Comment: I need multiple accounts as there are many people over here who just downvote your question, get it closed, or remove your access to ask questions even though the question was descriptive, well-formatted, and had the required codes. People should understand that newbies can not have the experience that many Experienced people have. And issues like in this question can happen to any newbie and the answers over here can help them ,as it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER BY clause is used here as per desired output ordering. It'll meet expectation.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT f.Primary_Brand_Key
     , t.Market
     , f.Food
     , t.TV_Spends
     , t.Print_Spends
     , COALESCE(t.TV_Spends, 0) + COALESCE(t.Print_Spends, 0) "Total_Spends"
FROM Food f
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Primary_Brand_Key
                  , Market
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN Medium = 'TV'
                                THEN Spent
                        END) "TV_Spends"
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN Medium = 'Print'
                                THEN Spent
                        END) "Print_Spends"
             FROM Brand
             WHERE Market IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY Primary_Brand_Key
                    , Market ) t
        ON f.Primary_Brand_Key = t.Primary_Brand_Key
ORDER BY f.food DESC, t.Market DESC;
```

As per new requirement type column is included in select list and null value in market row is also consider here.

```
-- Updated Query
SELECT f.Primary_Brand_Key
     , t.Market
     , t.Type
     , f.Food
     , t.TV_Spends
     , t.Print_Spends
     , COALESCE(t.TV_Spends, 0) + COALESCE(t.Print_Spends, 0) "Total_Spends"
FROM Food f
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Primary_Brand_Key
                  , Market
                  , MAX(Type) Type
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN Market IS NOT NULL
                                THEN CASE WHEN Medium = 'TV'
                                        THEN Spent
                                     END
                        END) "TV_Spends"
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN Market IS NOT NULL
                                THEN CASE WHEN Medium = 'Print'
                                        THEN Spent
                                     END
                        END) "Print_Spends"
             FROM Brand
             -- WHERE Market IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY Primary_Brand_Key
                    , Market ) t
        ON f.Primary_Brand_Key = t.Primary_Brand_Key
ORDER BY f.food DESC, t.Market DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, it is working. But however, The Market is showing the same values for all set of Primary_Brand. E.g. -

Primary_Brand Market Food TV_Spends Print_Spends Total_Spends
Kornet UK Yes 1000 NULL 1000
Kornet UK Yes 2000 3000 5000
Kornet Poland Yes 2000 3000 5000
Tamas UK No 9000 NULL 9000

Comment: Thanks @BerguruAdmin, Here I don't consider null value in market field. After checking I don't find Kornet UK Yes 2000 3000 5000 data. Please check and feel free to ask any query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed594/1/0

Comment: Thanks again @Rahul. However, the same market name is coming in for the one particular brand name. Instead, the market name should have only once per Brand Name. I am showing you here the output I am getting for my code. Please note it is the sample data only:-

Comment: Primary_Brand Year Month Category Medium Market IB_Type Period_Type Geography_Type Target_Group TV_spends Print_Spends
Yakis 2021 FEB Tea TV UK NULL FEB 2021 UK NULL 3751200.65 0.00
Yakis 2021 FEB Tea TV UK NULL FEB 2021 UK NULL 9440964.73 0.00
Yakis 2021 FEB Tea TV Poland NULL FEB 2021 Poland NULL 2.13 0.00
Yakis 2021 FEB Tea TV Poland NULL FEB 2021 Poland NULL 1342.66 0.00

Comment: Primary_Brand,Year,Month,Category,Medium,Market,IB_Type,Period_Type,Geography_Type,Target_Group,TV_spends,Print_Spends,Yakis,2021,FEB,Tea,TV,UK,NULL,FEB,2021,UK,NULL,3751200.65,0.00,Yakis,2021,FEB,Tea,TV,UK,NULL,FEB,2021,UK,NULL,9440964.73,0.00,Yakis,2021,FEB,Tea,TV,Poland,NULL,FEB,2021,Poland,NULL,2.13,0.00,Yakis,2021,FEB,Tea,TV,Poland,NULL,FEB,2021,Poland,NULL,1342.66,0.0

Comment: Hi @BerguruAdmin, as per your given data multiple market name in same primary_brand. Please give me expected output format if possibe.

Comment: Hi @Rahul : Sorry for the late response. I have updated the query & sample data

Comment: Hi @BerguruAdmin please check the url. Hope it'll meet expectation. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed594/18

Comment: Hi @Rahul : Thanks again for all your efforts. However, I don't know why I am getting the "Output Coming" when I implement the same logic as you shared in my query

Comment: Hi @BerguruAdmin: As you want to consider null valued market row so disable WHERE clause and all amount field is set zero(0) where market value is null. Also you can ignore GROUP BY clause as you don't use any aggregate function in retrieval select list. For large data it will generate extra cost. Also remove comma(,) after type because comma is used before sum started. Please check the url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed594/25

Answer (score 0):

Although your question was not clear, I had to use some nested queries.

```
select T.Primary_Brand_Key as Primary_Brand,Market,Food,TV_Spends,Print_Spends,ISNULL(TV_Spends,0) + ISNULL(Print_Spends,0) as Total_Spends
from
(select *,
    case when 1=1 then (select top 1 Spent from brand b where b.Primary_Brand_Key = T.Primary_Brand_Key and b.Market = T.Market and b.Medium = 'Print') else 0 end as Print_Spends
from
   (select t2.*,
         case when Medium = 'TV' then Spent else 0 end as TV_Spends
    from
       (select Primary_Brand_Key,Market 
        from Brand
        group by Primary_Brand_Key,Market) t1
        join Brand t2 on t1.Primary_Brand_Key = t2.Primary_Brand_Key and t1.Market = t2.Market) T
where TV_Spends > 0) T join Food F on T.Primary_Brand_Key = F.Primary_Brand_Key 
order by TV_Spends
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f402dca49b6d7749963400ea340242ab)